# Gstreamer RTSP Server over UDP artifacts on video when there is a packet loss

Tags: ffmpeg, gstreamer, rtsp, rtp, libav

I want to have a RTSP server which should work on top of UDP , but when I tried to use Gstreamer RTSP server its giving video artifact/glitches when there is a packet loss.

I have tried to follow  [this example for RTSP re-transmission](https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-rtsp-server/blob/master/examples/test-video-rtx.c).

`gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_profiles (factory, GST_RTSP_PROFILE_AVPF);`

When the profile is set like above , ffmpeg / mplayer  / VLC is not able to play and says that it is an unsupported protocol. I don't know which player supports this protocol, only the gstreamer player is able to play the video.

When the `gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_profiles` line  is removed then all the players are working but there is a lot of artifact on the video if there is packet loss.

everything is working fine on local env but on cloud there are artifact because of packet loss

I also tried making retransission_time to 10 sec but it did not work.

`gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_retransmission_time (factory, 10000 * GST_MSECOND);`

Tried enabling RTCP as required for NACK (did not work i can see RTCP messages in wireshark )

`gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_enable_rtcp(factory , 1);`

Tried setting  retransmission true (Did not worked )

`gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_do_retransmission(factory,1);`

I still get the artifacts / glitches on the video some time video just stuck on the client side

I can confirm that its due to packet loss because when i switch the RTSP to use  TCP instead of UDP everything works fine.

Comment: The client needs to send the feedback which frames to re-send. If the client does not tell the sender there is little the sender can do. So if a client does not support AVPF I guess it cannot work.

Comment: thanks @FlorianZwoch for the info so  do you know any RTSP client other then gstreamer which support ACPF. Because I tried all the major clients such as ffmpeg / VLC / Mplayer.

Comment: Just a private implementation that had it. Perhaps maybe also look at FEC. It adds a flat overhead compared to retransmission, but also helps to mitigate packet loss.

Comment: When using udp for rtsp Transport and there is packet loss it is of course normal that u have artifacts because data is missing or lost, decrase frame Rate, Bitrate or Resolution to reduce Data that is Transmitted, or increase compression, you could switch to TCP but then U had increased Latency and Video that is not fluently. So in General your Connection is to Bad for the qualitiy u want to transmitt. Only reducing Data would be do a better result at end

Comment: @Christoph yes you are right but I am expecting RTSP to recover the packet loss by using NACK mechanism (re-transmission of lost packets )

Comment: Ok, but then u need to get sure both sites are correctly configured and use RTCP NACK because client needs to inform server when it has loss a package. You get this out of the box with TCP, without special configuration on both sites. The question is how important latency is, for my perspective it's always better to lose some packages and have artifacts instead of having an increasing latency when connection is bad. It doesn't matter if u use UDP with NACK or TCP because packages need to be retransmitted and latency increase over time to a value that is no acceptable.